# AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'query_params'

Tags: python, django, csv, templates

I'm trying to pull data from the site on the backend side everything will work: link from where I pull all the data
https://swapi.dev/api/people

```
count = {'count': 0, "next_page": 1, 'dates': [],}

starwars = [count, ]
# class StarView(APIView):

#     def get(self, request):
#         page = request.query_params.get('page', 1)
#         if starwars[0]['next_page'] == int(page):
#             url = f'https://swapi.dev/api/people/?page={page}'
#             response = requests.get(url).json()
#             starwars.append(response['results'])
#             starwars[0]['count'] += 10
#             starwars[0]['next_page'] += 1
#             starwars[0]['dates'].append(datetime.today())
#             with open('story.csv', 'w') as file:
#                 file.write(str(starwars[0]))
#                 for i in range(1, len(starwars)):
#                     for j in starwars[i]:
#                         file.write('\n')
#                         file.write(str(j))
#             return Response(starwars, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
#         return Response({"error": "Enter valid page"})
```

But as soon as I decided to create a template def index ..... for the place of this code, I get this error how to fix it (AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'query_params')

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        page = request.query_params.get('page', 1)
        if starwars[0]['next_page'] == int(page):
            url = f'https://swapi.dev/api/people/?page={page}'
            response = requests.get(url).json()
            starwars.append(response['results'])
            starwars[0]['count'] += 10
            starwars[0]['next_page'] += 1
            starwars[0]['dates'].append(datetime.today())
            with open('story.csv', 'w') as file:
                file.write(str(starwars[0]))
                for i in range(1, len(starwars)):
                    for j in starwars[i]:
                        file.write('\n')
                        file.write(str(j))
            return render(request,('index.html'))
        return Response({"error": "Enter valid page"})
```

What am I even trying to do? I need to send a request to view data. 10 fixed data are displayed. When you click on the view button, more data should appear, that is, in total, 20 of them will already be displayed. All this is saved in a csv file. How to implement a view more button? Here is my only template.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>People</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="GET">

{% csrf_token %}

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `APIView` transforms the request, you can not use `query_params` with a "vanilla" view.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thanks for the reply but I still don't understand. What needs to be done to make it work?